# Error to install composer on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy the `Laravel` app to `AWS EB` via `pipeline` when I deploy the app I got error in Recent events when I check the log file last 100 line I found this error:

```
2020/10/18 00:43:08.443797 [INFO] Executing instruction: Install composer dependencies
2020/10/18 00:43:08.443819 [INFO] installing composer dependencies...
2020/10/18 00:43:08.443859 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction 
2020/10/18 00:43:08.482582 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [Install composer dependencies]. 
Stop running the command. Error: installing composer dependencies failed with error: Command /bin/sh -c composer.phar install --no-ansi --no-interaction  failed with error exit status 254. Stderr:Sun Oct 18 00:43:08 2020 (12045):
Fatal Error Insufficient shared memory!
```

I have file called `01_deploy.config` inside `.ebextensions` conatins this:

```
option_settings:
# Point the app root to the public/ folder.
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: document_root
    value: /public

# Set here your php.ini `memory_limit` value.
- namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:php:phpini
    option_name: memory_limit
    value: 256M

container_commands:
01_install_composer_dependencies:
    command: "sudo php /usr/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader"
    cwd: "/var/app/current"

02_install_node_dependencies:
    command: "sudo npm install"
    cwd: "/var/app/current"

 05_run_migrations:
   command: "php artisan migrate --force"
   cwd: "/var/app/current"
   leader_only: true
```

Edit:

```
2020/10/18 10:28:58.643232 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-2:129692188551:stack/awseb-e-ptmhtrxjzh-stack/af3b2a70-0ce0-11eb-8981-0618bcd9a382 -r AWSEBAutoScalingGroup --region us-east-2 --configsets Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild

2020/10/18 10:29:45.306985 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [PostBuildEbExtension]. 
Stop running the command. Error: Container commands build failed. Please refer to /var/log/cfn-init.log for more details.
```

Edit2: for last error

```
    2020-10-18 10:39:44,791 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 05_run_migrations failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 129, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 530, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 542, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 260, in build
    changes['commands'] = CommandTool().apply(self._config.commands)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 117, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
ToolError: Command 05_run_migrations failed
```

Comment: "Insufficient shared memory!" - probably need more memory. What instance type are you using?

Comment: @Marcin it's tc2.micro! but I didnot choose that, it just created from EB by default

Comment: You can try with greater instance. You can change the instance type in EB configuration menu.

Comment: @Marcin I changed it  to small instance, then deploy I got new error ( Updated question)

Comment: Can you check ` /var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log` and see which command failed and why?

Comment: @Marcin Man!!! the app is crashed and show in the head title of the website this warring (potential security risk ahead) !!!!

Comment: Have you identified what causes "Error: Container commands build failed."?

Comment: @Marcin yes, please see the edit 2

Comment: Maybe its because `container_commands`  run in `/var/app/staging` folder, not `/var/app/current` as you try to run them.

Comment: @Marcin change it to staging but still get same error

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what else you can try.

Comment: @Marcin Don't worry man! you are my king in AWS! helped me a lot, big thanks :)

Comment: No problem. If you figure it out, please let me know. I'm curious of the solution to the issue.

Comment: @Marcin I will! can I have your any social media account to follow you :) if you active on it!

Comment: You can just comment in SO and reference me:-)

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: You may install composer locally and include the vendor folder on zip archive while sending it to Elastic Beanstalk

Option 2: Use this container_command

```
command: "sudo php -d memory_limit=-1 /usr/bin/composer.phar install --no-dev --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader"
```